# How to check if dependencies of an app installed via software manager are removed?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center

I removed KeePassXC via the software manager but I'm not sure if its dependencies have been removed too. Is there any way to check for this? Other threads say that sudo apt-get purge can be used but I'm very new to linux and am not sure how to get the package name of an app installed via software manager

Answer (score 0):

The graphical software store does not have a feature to remove unneeded dependencies, I'm afraid.

For applications which were `deb` format and thus installed under the covers using `apt` / `apt-get` then you can issue the following command to remove unneeded dependencies:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

If the application you removed was a `snap`, then the dependencies are mostly bundled with the application and get removed with it. However there are some additional snaps that get pulled in by the snap, which may or may not be used by other snaps on your system. In the case of the `keepassxc` snap (at the time of writing) it uses a `core18` base snap, and `gtk-common-themes` shared content snap. It's possible to remove these if they're not in use by other snaps with the following command:

```
snap remove gtk-common-themes
```

You likely have other snaps using the `core18` base snap though, so it's probably not possible or desirable to remove it.